# how to insert checkbox & file field value in database in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following code in php file:

```
include_once('connection.php');
$prod_imgs='';
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $category_id=$_REQUEST['category']; 
    $product_id=$_REQUEST['product'];
    $relation_id=$_REQUEST['relation'];
    $occasion_id=$_REQUEST['occasion'];
    $prod_image = $_FILES['prod_image']['name'];

    $tot=count($prod_image);
    $tott=count($occasion_id);
    //$tott=count($occasion);
    foreach($prod_image as $key=>$prod_imgs)
    {
        if($prod_imgs==="")
        {
            unset($prod_image[$key]);
            $prod_image[] = $prod_imgs;
            echo $key.$prod_imgs;
        }

    }

        for($i=0;$i<$tott;$i++)
        {

        if($prod_image!='')
        {
             $prod_images=$prod_image[$i];
            $occasion=$occasion_id[$i];

            //$image=$prod_images[$i];  
            //echo $prod_images=$prod_image[$i];

        if(mysql_query("insert into tbl_add_product_occasion                            values('','$category_id','$product_id','$relation_id','$occasion','product_images/$prod_images')")or die(mysql_error()))
    {
        $msg="<script>alert('your product info added successfully')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('an error occured!!!')</script>";
    }

    }
    }
echo $msg;
}

& the html is:





<script type="text/javascript">
function get_product(cat){      
                                  // alert(cat);
                                   $.ajax({
                                      type : "POST",
                                      url : 'ajax_get_product.php',
                                      data : 'cat=' +cat,
                                      success : function(data){
                                        //alert(data);
                                        document.getElementById('prod').innerHTML=data;
                                            //society_code').innerH''TML=data.d;
                                         }
                                      });

        };


</script>
<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <fieldset>
                 <dl>
                        <dt><label for="gender">Select category:</label></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <select  name="category" id="category" onchange="get_product(this.value)" >
                                <option>select category</option>
                                <?php
                                $sel=mysql_query("select * from tbl_category");
                                while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
                                {
                                    $id=$arr['id'];
                                    echo "<option value='".$id."'>".$arr['category']."</option>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                    <dt><label for="product">Select Product:</label></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <select name="product" id="prod">
                                <option value=''>select product</option>

                            </select>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>

                    <dl>
                    <dt><label for="option">choose relation:</label></dt>
                    <dd>
                    <select name="relation">
                    <?php
                    $query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_relation");
                    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        $relation=$result['relation'];
                        $relation_id=$result['id'];
                        echo "<option value='".$relation_id."'>".$relation."</option>";         

                    }?>
                    s</select>
                    </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                    <dt><label for="option">choose Occasion:</label></dt>
                    <div style="float:left;width: 400px;margin-top: 9px;">
                    <?php
                        $select=mysql_query('select * from tbl_occasion');
                        while($array=mysql_fetch_array($select))
                        {
                            $occasion_id=$array['id'];
?>


<dd style="width:auto;">
<span id="" style="width:115px; float:left;"><input type="checkbox" name="occasion[]" value="<?php echo $occasion_id;?>" /><?php echo $array['occasion'];?></span>
<input type="file" name="prod_image[]"/>

</dd>

<?php
}
?>
                    </div>
                    </dl>
                    <dl class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
                     </dl>
                </fieldset>

             </form>
```

when i am inserting the data into my table image not inserting in database other is fine working well but image not inserting . please help me to solve this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: your image column data type ??

Answer (score 0):

You should abandon the use of the deprecated mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or PDO instead. Don't concatenate strings, use prepared statements with parameters instead. Bind your input values to the parameters. That said:

The PHP-manual says (http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory, unless another location has been given with the upload_tmp_dir directive in php.ini.

[...]

Whatever the logic, you should either delete the file from the temporary directory or move it elsewhere.

---

You should move the uploaded file with [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), before you're working with it.

Comment: hello VMai sir, i tried it with move_uploaded_file() function here i not used it becuase i will upload the images through ftp.here i just want to insert the image path only. & the problem is it's count the all images in loop wherever checkbox count only checked value so thatwy its problem occured loop is running accroding to checkbox so image field is inserted blank..

Answer (score 0):

add this code in form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

checkbox value : <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="play"> play
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="game" required>game

file name : <input type="file" name="img" required>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
 

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{
# $_FILES — HTTP File Upload variables
$img = $_FILES['img']['name'];

$checkbox = $_POST['chk'];
# implode() returns a string from the elements of an array.
$chk = implode(",",$checkbox);

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");

$q ="insert into table (image,checkbox) values ('$img','$chk')";
mysqli_query($link,$q);
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you expand your answer?  Also, it might help to read the help section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Please edit your answer and put your explanation there.